# How to parse Soap Header with xpath in SoapHandler

Tags: java, soap, xpath

I have develop a soap handler which intercept inbound message and retrieve values from SoapHeader.

i use following code to read soapheader

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage=  context.getMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnvelope.getHeader();
```

Now how i can create Document from SOAPHeader object so i can use that in xPathExpression.evaluate

From Document i mean org.w3c.dom.Document.

I got answer

We can create document by following code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

soapMessage.writeTo(out); 

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( out.toByteArray() ); 
doc = docBuilder.parse( is );
```

Regards,
imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can directly apply parsing on soapheader like following

NodeList nodes =soapHeader.getElementsByTagName("param");

No need of xpath.

Regards,